# Let $x \in \mathbb{C}[G]$ such that $x.x =0$. Then $x=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm looking for a proof or a counter-example of the following statement.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathbb{C}[G]$ its group algebra. Let $x \in \mathbb{C}[G]$ such that $x.x =0$. Then $x=0$

Comment: What does $x.x$ mean here?

Comment: Assuming that $x.x$ denotes multiplication in the group algebra, then, writing $x = \sum_{g \in G} \lambda_g g$, use the fact that $x^2 = \sum_{g,h \in G} (\lambda_g \lambda_h) (gh)$ to conclude that if $x^2 = 0$, then $\lambda_g \lambda_h = 0, \forall g,h \in G$.

Comment: It is the usual product in the group algebra defined as follow. Let $G=\{g_1,...g_n\}$, take two general vectors of $\mathbb{C}[G]$, $v_=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_ig_i$ and $w=\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_ig_i$ with complex coefficients, then $v.w=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}c_id_j(g_ig_j)$ with the product $g_ig_j$ defined as the group multiplication.

Comment: If $\sum_{g,h\in G}(\lambda_g \lambda_h)(gh)=0$, I can only conclude that the coefficients of each basis vector are 0. How can I then say $\lambda_g\lambda_h=0 \ \forall g,h$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is isomorphic to a product of matrix algebras $M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ (one for each conjugation class). So it has a whole lot of nilpotent elements, including of nilpotence order $2$, unless $G$ is abelian (in which case all the $n_i$ are $1$ so $\mathbb{C}[G]\simeq \mathbb{C}^{|G|}$ is reduced).